# Innertext returning an object in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using the following in puppeteer to try return the number in the inner text of the below element. I've tried many different ways but keep getting an empty object returned, what am I doing wrong?!

```
if (await page.$('.s-pagination-item.s-pagination-next.s-pagination-button.s-pagination-separator') !== null) {
  var lastPageNumber = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('s-pagination-item.s-pagination-disabled'), a => a.innerText);
} else {
  var lastPageNumber = 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the `innerText` value of a given object you would need to do it like this:

```
var lastPageNumber = await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelector('s-pagination-item.s-pagination-disabled').innerText
);
```